# Is there any way to name external threads?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

TThread.NameThreadForDebugging is great for telling threads apart, but not all of my threads are TThread descendants.  I have some that are created by an external library that's not even written in Delphi.  Is there any way to name them if I can find a way to get their thread handles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this MSDN article: [How to: Set a Thread Name in Native Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx)

This works for Visual Studio.  I don't know whether the Delphi debugger will pick up the name.

Note that you need the thread ID rather than the thread handle.

Comment: Yeah, the Delphi RTL function appears to be almost an exact translation of this bit of C++.  But in the helpfile it says "ThreadID is the ThreadID property of the TThread instance to be named."  So is that just a reflection of a thread ID assigned by Windows?

Comment: You might want to be aware of following quirk - I am not sure if it applies to Delphi debugger as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448155/setthreadname-not-working-with-visual-studio-2005

Comment: No, that looks to be specific to Visual Studio.